# How can I transmit data (save), only if there are changes (in textarea)?

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, save

The user shall be able to edit **two textareas** ( one, only if he has permissions[but this doesnt matter here] ) and after clicking the "save"-button, the data shall be deliverd, but only in the area, where changes were made.
because if not - **my current problem**: *the other textarea ( when there were no changes ) will be saved with a null value*

When the user only edits one area, it only shall deliver the new change.

**Here is my JS**

```
....
$scope.data = {
          newCustomerSignature: '',
          newAccountSignature: '',
          user: '',
          permissions: []
        };
 $scope.saveSignature = function () {

          AccountCustomer.one().get().then(
              function (resultOk) {
                var accountCustomer = resultOk.data;
                accountCustomer.signature = $scope.data.newCustomerSignature;
                accountCustomer.put().then(
                    Accounts.one().get().then(
                    function (resultOk) {
                      var account = resultOk.data;
                      account.signature = $scope.data.newAccountSignature;
                      account.put().then(
                          function (resultOk) {
                            $scope.formSignature.$setPristine();
                            $log.d("Saved");
                            $log.d("Accountinfo ok: ", resultOk);
                            $scope.data.user = resultOk.data;
                          },
                          function (resultError) {
                            $log.d("Accountinfo error: ", resultError);
                            ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
                          }
                      );
                    }
                ));
              }
          );
        };
```

**here is my HTML**

```
....
<form name="formSignature">
    <div>
      <i> Persönliche Signatur </i><br/>

      <textarea id="persSignature" name="persSignature"
                rows="5" cols="40"
                use-sms-counter="data.smsCounter"
                ng-model="data.newAccountSignature"
                ng-trim="false"
                placeholder="{{data.user.signature}}">
      </textarea>

      <div>
        <div class="amount"
             data-sms-counter="data.smsCounter"
             data-sms-counter-content-list="[data.newAccountSignature]"
             data-max-messages="1">
        </div>
.....
```

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

But when I only want to change one textarea, **the other one will be set to an empty value**

[image]

Comment: So, you only want to allow the user to submit the form if that particular model was changed?

Comment: The user shall be able to submit at any time.
but I only want the date to be transmitted, if there were changes in the form
in other ways, a "null" value would be transmitted

I will post an example

Comment: I suppose you could check the $dirty property of the inputs in your SaveSignature function and if the first text area is unchanged ($pristine) and the second is $dirty, set the values accordingly. If both are $dirty then you know both were changed. Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue   the $scope has a reference to the form and the controls on the form.